# Is there a way to align a geo json file on top of a terrain map perfectly? React, D3 and Three js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, three.js, geojson

I have a Europe terrain map made from some DEM files which were then combined into one binary file. Then this file is read in React and the map is created. This can also be created using a simple heightmap but for the sake of this application I have to use the binary file.

Now when I have a terrain map I would like to add counties' borders using a geojson file to create geometries. The componentDidMount function is shown in the snippet below:

```js
const SIZE_AMPLIFIER = 20;
const WIDTH = 2500 * SIZE_AMPLIFIER;
var container = document.getElementById("main_map");
var renderer, scene, camera;
var terrainData;

//load map datd from bin file
function loadTerrain(file) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
  xhr.open('GET', file, true);
  xhr.onload = function (evt) {
    if (xhr.response) {
      terrainData = new Uint16Array(xhr.response)
      init();
    }

  };
  xhr.send(null);
}

loadTerrain('stats.bin');

function init() {

  // initialize camera
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, .1, 100000);
  camera.position.set(9191, 15000, 21000);

  // initialize scene
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var containerWidth = container.getBoundingClientRect().right - container.getBoundingClientRect().left;

  // initialize directional light (sun)
  var sun = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFFFFFF, 1.0);
  sun.position.set(300, 400, 300);
  sun.distance = 1000;
  scene.add(sun);

  var frame = new THREE.SpotLightHelper(sun);
  scene.add(frame);

  // initialize renderer
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setClearColor(0x006994);
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(containerWidth, containerWidth / 2 + 150);
  container.append(renderer.domElement);

  //initialize controls
  var controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  controls.enableDamping = true;
  controls.dampingFactor = 1;
  controls.rotateSpeed = .8;
  //controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2 - .3;

  //initialize plane ***** 999, 999 because file size is 1000x1000
  var terrainGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(WIDTH, WIDTH, 999, 999);
  terrainGeometry.castShadow = true;
  terrainGeometry.receiveShadow = true;

  var heightsArray = terrainGeometry.attributes.position.array;

  // apply height map to vertices of terrainGeometry
  for (let i = 0, j = 2; i < terrainData.length; i += 1, j += 3) {
    if (terrainData[i] == 0) {
      heightsArray[j] = terrainData[i]
    } else {
      heightsArray[j] = terrainData[i] / 65535 * 480 + 10
    }
  }

  var colorsArray = new Float32Array(heightsArray.length);
  var waterLevel = 1.7;
  var adjustHeight = 10 + waterLevel// 0.1 ~ 50cm water level, starts from 1.7

  function addColors(counterJ, colorR, colorG, colorB) {
    colorsArray[counterJ] = new THREE.Color(colorR).r;
    colorsArray[counterJ + 1] = new THREE.Color(colorG).g;
    colorsArray[counterJ + 2] = new THREE.Color(colorB).b;
  }

  for (let i = 2, j = 0; i < heightsArray.length; i += 3, j += 3) {

    if (heightsArray[i] >= 0 && heightsArray[i] < 350 / adjustHeight) {
      addColors(j, 0x000000, 0x006900, 0x000094);
    }
    else if (heightsArray[i] >= 350 / adjustHeight && heightsArray[i] < 900 / adjustHeight) {
      addColors(j, 0x6e0000, 0x00dc00, 0x00006e);
    }
    else if (heightsArray[i] >= 900 / adjustHeight && heightsArray[i] < 1300 / adjustHeight) {
      addColors(j, 0xf00000, 0x00fa00, 0x0000a0);
    }
    else if (heightsArray[i] >= 1300 / adjustHeight && heightsArray[i] < 1900 / adjustHeight) {
      addColors(j, 0xe00000, 0x0bd00, 0x000077);
    }
    else if (heightsArray[i] >= 1900 / adjustHeight && heightsArray[i] < 2500 / adjustHeight) {
      addColors(j, 0xdd0000, 0x009800, 0x000056);
    }
    else if (heightsArray[i] >= 2500 / adjustHeight && heightsArray[i] < 3300 / adjustHeight) {
      addColors(j, 0xa00000, 0x005200, 0x00002d);
    }
    else {
      addColors(j, 0xd20000, 0x00d200, 0x0000d2);
    }

  }

  terrainGeometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(heightsArray, 3));
  terrainGeometry.setAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(colorsArray, 3))

  var terrainMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors, side: THREE.DoubleSide
  })

  var terrainMesh = new THREE.Mesh(terrainGeometry, terrainMaterial);
  terrainMesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
  terrainMesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
  terrainMesh.updateMatrix();

  terrainGeometry.computeFaceNormals();
  terrainGeometry.computeVertexNormals();

  scene.add(terrainMesh);

  const width1 = terrainGeometry.parameters.width; //2500 * SIZE_AMPLIFIER,
  const projection = d3.geoTransverseMercator().rotate([-10, 0, 0]) //center meridian

      .center([10, 52]) //longitude, latitude
      .scale(width1 * 1.55); //scale
  const path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);
  const svg = d3.select("#Map").append("svg")

  d3.json('/Europe1.geo.json')
    .then(topology => {

      svg.selectAll(".country")
        .data(topology.features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", ".country")
        .attr("d", path)

      var svgMarkup = svg.node().outerHTML;
      var loader = new SVGLoader();
      var svgData = loader.parse(svgMarkup);

      var svgGroup = new THREE.Group();
      svgData.paths.forEach((path, i) => {
        var shapes = path.toShapes(true);


        shapes.forEach((shape, j) => {
         
          var geomSVG = new THREE.ExtrudeBufferGeometry(shape, {
            depth: 10,
            bevelEnabled: false
          })

          //needed for click event!
          // var materialSVG = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
          //   color: 0xFFFFFF,
          //   transparent: true,
          //   opacity: 0,
          // });

          //var meshSVG = new THREE.Mesh(geomSVG, materialSVG);
          //svgGroup.add(meshSVG);

          //create borders
          var borderMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x000000, linewidth: 3 })
          var borderGeometry = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(geomSVG, 15);
          var bordermesh = new THREE.LineSegments(borderGeometry, borderMaterial);
     
          svgGroup.add(bordermesh);

        })
      })

      var axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(50000);
      scene.add(axesHelper);

      svgGroup.rotateX(Math.PI / 2)

      scene.add(svgGroup);
      svg.remove();

    })

  animate();
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

I am sure that this is the correct projection.

[ETRS_1989_LAEA projection](https://gist.github.com/allardw/5c8d088103c5bfd83a903eba5dee37e1)

The problem has to be in the scale but I am not capable of scaling it perfectly in order to fit on the map. The best I could achieve:

[image]

I am new to threejs and this seems impossible to me, I would really appreaciate your help!

Comment: Both the source data for the terrain height and the country boundaries have to use the same projection of the Earth. There are [about a hundred official ways to project a map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_map_projections), so are you sure they're identical? Because there shouldn't be a need for scaling if they're both the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am completely sure they are identical. I managed to somehow adjust it by increasing the height of the terrain map and with a lot of hardcoded numbers.